# Proteger opções de utilizador de outros utilizadores

Tags: php

Tou a desenvolver um sistema onde cada utilizador tem opções de eliminar, adicionar, ou atualizar, seja o que for.
Imaginemos que eu, como utilizador logado com ID=6 tenho as opções de eliminar uma das minhas fotos.

Quando clico numa das minhas fotos é através de um link como este

`photo_op.php?id=42&p=images/user/QzEckSX.png&o=6`

onde o `?id=` ao id da imagem, o `&p=` ao caminho da imagem e o `&o=` a quem pertence a imagem, neste caso `o=6`.

Estou a verificar se a foto é do utilizador logado, se for então exibo as opções, se não for então só mostra a imagem. Desta forma:

```
$id_user=$_SESSION['id'];
$owner=$_REQUEST['o'];


if ($owner != $id_user){
    echo "";

}else{
echo "<div id='photo_op'><a href='eliminar_photo_p.php?id=$id_photo'></a> ";
echo "<a href='add_photo_p.php?id=$id_photo'></a></div>";
}
```

O problema é que o utilizador com id=11 se "injetar" o ID=6 no link que pertence ao ID=6, o utilizador de ID=11 tem acesso às opções do utilizador ID=6.

Qual a melhor forma de exibir as opções ao utilizador sem que este possa sofrer de injeção na url?

Por exemplo, sendo eu o proprietário da imagem tenho este link:

`photo_op.php?id=42&p=images/user/QzEckSX.png&o=6`

Mas se o outro utilizador de id=11 fizer isto:

`photo_op.php?id=42&p=images/user/QzEckSX.png&o=11`

ele vai ter acesso às opções de eliminar essa foto a que ele não pertence.

O meu ficheiro login.php está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
include('init.php');


//echo $_POST['txtemail'];
//echo $_POST['txtpassword'];


//CONSULTA DO UTILIZADOR
$consulta="Select * from user where email='" . $_POST['txtemail'] . "' and     senha='" . $_POST['txtpassword'] . "'";
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta);
if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0) //SE O EMAIL E A PASSWORD COINCIDIREM
{
//COLOCA NA VARIAVEL LINHA OS DADOS DA CONSULTA
$linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
//COLOCA O EMAIL EM SESSAO
$_SESSION['email']=$linha['email'];
$_SESSION['username']=$linha['username'];
$_SESSION['id']=$linha['id'];
$_SESSION['status']=$linha['status'];
$_SESSION['genero']=$linha['genero'];



$_SESSION['last_login']=$linha['last_login'];
$_SESSION['nlog']=$linha['nlog'];
//REDIRECCIONA A PAGINA PARA A PAGINA SECRETA
include('q/status_update.php');
include('q/nlog_update.php');
header("location: home.php");
}
else //CASO NÃO COINCIDAM
{
//REDIRECCIONA PARA A PAGINA INICIAL REPORTANDO O ERRO
header("location: index.php?erro=1");
}



?>
```

O meu `get_photos.php` é o seguinte:

```
<?php 
$id_s=$_SESSION['id'];
$sql ="SELECT id, user_id, location FROM photos WHERE user_id=$id_s";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


echo " <a class='galeria_p' onclick='goclicky(this); return false;'   target='_blank' href='q/photo_op.php?  id=".$row['id']."&p=".$row['location']."&o=".$id_s." ' ><img class='img1'   width='118px' height='118px' src=".$row['location']."></a> ";      

}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: Existe algum sistema de autenticação? Como você sabe quais imagens pertencem ao utilizador? Se existe algum sistema de autenticação, é preciso verificar se o recurso solicitado pertence ao utilizador logado.

Comment: Sim, o utilizador faz login, após o login feito eu exibo, neste caso as imagens, conforme o id de utilizador logado. Vou buscar elas na base de dados através do id de utilizador logado por exemplo: `$sql ="SELECT id, user_id, location FROM photos WHERE user_id=$id";` e assim recebo as fotos do utilizador logado

Comment: E onde o id do utilizador logado é armazenado após login? Você está deixando essa responsabilidade no lado do cliente, ou seja, é o cliente que informa qual o seu ID. Se o ID é crucial para bloquear acessos indevidos, não deveria ser informado no link e sim ser gravado em uma  session, por exemplo, e ser incluído na query. Procure por PHP login session.

Comment: Você pode até manter o ID do utilizador na URL, porém não utilize na busca pelas imagens. Utilize para comparar se o ID informado é o mesmo que está armazenado na sua session, se sim, mostra o recurso, se não mostra a mensagem a dizer que o recurso não pertence ao utilizador.

Comment: Coloque também na pergunta o código onde o utilizador faz o login, assim posso utiliza-lo para dar um exemplo de como utilizar uma session.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Amigo, obrigado pela atenção. Coloquei o meu ficheiro `login.php` na questão

Comment: Ok percebi, você já utiliza session. Qual a sua query para buscar a imagem? Você certamente na tabela onde armazena as imagens também tem o id do utilizador a qual ela pertence, certo? Coloque na pergunta a estrutura da sua tabela de imagens (campos) e a query para buscar a imagem.

Comment: Certo @FilipeMoraes . Na tabela `photos` tenho  o campo `user_id` que guarda o `id` do utilizador que fez o upload da foto. A query é esta mesmo, `$sql ="SELECT id, user_id, location FROM photos WHERE user_id=$id";`

Comment: Então, coloque na sua query na clausura where a seguinte verificação: `user_id=$_SESSION['id']`. Posta o codigo completo, onde inclui a query.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes coloquei na questão o meu `get_photos.php`

Comment: Outra vez, apesar de sempre falar aqui, vejo um sistema de login que salva as senhas de forma pura. Alem de permitir um sql injection. :( todo o seu problema esta na modelagem, nem é na codificação, esta pensando errado. Se existisse no banco um relacionamento entre usuário e imagem, não passaria por isso, alem do mais ia se livrar de ter que passar o caminho da imagem, ja que só passaria o ID da mesma e ID é algo único

Comment: @RenatoTavares existe sim um relacionamento entre utilizador e imagem, está la na pergunta, veja o código `get_photos.php`. Entretanto concordo com você que gravar senhas puras é um problema de segurança, mas não é o problema proposto na pergunta, por isso não falei sobre o assunto.

Comment: As senhas estão a ser inseridas puras sim.Pelo menos para já em fase de teste. Quando tiver o meu sistema completo vou passar a "pente fino" cada uma das variáveis

Comment: Então pq passa o caminho da foto, se pelo relacionamento (em teoria), teria todos os dados da imagem, tipo descrição, quem é o dono, quem pode fazer o que com a foto....  Sendo desta forma somente necessário validar o usuário logado, em em seguida saber se a foto é dele mesmo, um if ja faria.. mas tb so estou comentando

Comment: Amigo @RenatoTavares tem alguma página onde eu poderia ler mais sobre o assunto? As relações que voce fala são feitas diretamente no `PHPmyAdmin`?

Comment: @DavidConcha basicamente o que ele está a dizer é que a sua tabela de imagens poderia conter além do dono da imagem, o diretório onde ele se encontra, assim você não precisa passa-la na URL, aliás, para que você está passando o diretório da imagem na URL? Bom, de qualquer modo respondemos a questão inicial.

Comment: Para usar como background a imagem selecionada. `html{    background:url(<?php $photo_path=$_REQUEST['p']; echo"../$photo_path "?>) no-repeat center center fixed; 

  
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes, terá que verificar se a imagem pertence ao utilizador logado:

Vamos remover a linha `$owner=$_REQUEST['o'];` porque a responsabilidade de informar quem é o dono da imagem não é do cliente e sim do servidor. Deixar o cliente dizer se é ou não o dono da imagem é uma falha de segurança.

É a mesma coisa que você chegar num condomínio fechado e pedir para entrar no apartamento e o porteiro deixar só porque você disse que é o dono.

```
$id_user = $_SESSION['id'];

// Vamos remover um possível ataque via sql injection
// Atenção que no PHP 5.5.0 em diante o método mysql_real_escape_string 
// e a extensão mysql são deprecated, ou seja, 
// serão removidos de versões futuras (o PHP 7 já removeu penso eu).
// Passe a utilizar a extensão mysqli (com "i" no fim).
$id_photo = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']);

$sql ="SELECT 1 FROM photos WHERE id=$id_photo AND user_id=$id_user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div id='photo_op'><a href='eliminar_photo_p.php?id=$id_photo'></a> ";
    echo "<a href='add_photo_p.php?id=$id_photo'></a></div>";
} else {
    echo "Seu malandro! Você não é o dono da imagem!";
}
```

Comment: Essa variável `$owner` é substituída pelo `$id` da foto?

Comment: @DavidConcha atualizei o código, tinha um erro. Faça refresh e veja a resposta. A variavel `$owner` já não existe.

Comment: @DavidConcha fiz novamente um update. Peço desculpas, estou a codificar no próprio editor do SOpt.

Comment: Muito obrigado! era mesmo isso, eu não estava a pensar da melhor forma. A sua solução resolveu meu problema! muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: @DavidConcha que ótimo. Entretanto sugiro algumas alterações no seu código, por exemplo, não armazene a senha do utilizador pura, se a base de dados cair nas mãos erradas, todas as senhas serão comprometidas (mesmo criptografada já está dependendo do nível da dificuldade da senha). Procure sobre PHP Bcrypt por exemplo, procure também sobre SQL Injection para saber como tratar a suas variáveis antes de injeta-las na query, procure utilizar mysqli (com "i") no lugar de mysql, uma vez que está em desuso.

Comment: Eu estava a pensar deixar assim enquanto o projeto não é concluído. Não deixarei as password assim quando colocar o sistema online. Irei sim dar uma olhada em PHP Bcrypt. Obrigado pelas dicas!